# Not able to download app code from ionic view app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

I am using ionic 2 to build my app. I have uploaded my app to ionic view. My app id is 779eb729

I lost my code locally.

How can i download the code uploaded to ionic view?

I have tried the following

Entering app Id to download it as a zip using the below link.
https://apps.ionic.io/settings/data

Getting error as below.

```
 <Error>
 <script/>
 <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
 The specified key does not exist.</Message>
 <Key>e5ca31a4-6c38-11e7-8adb-0a16d4594913.zip</Key>
 <RequestId>214F9C8D72CC27EF</RequestId>
 <HostId>

m7KAm/NPBiADxHzhMs8z9lbqHEQni+4wvxRHNlK+tyTH9JHDcsW95hhqth87u2Ds7XrpJZCbwoU=
 </HostId>
```

`'

Using ionic view app.
I dont seee my apps listed in the app when i click on load app.

I can see the list when i log into pc, not in mobile app.

Can u pls help me in downloading the app. My app id is 779eb729

Comment: `app has no files` saying ionic view, seems like upload was not successful, i. suggest to create an issue at https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cloud

Comment: did you generate apk before? how you lost your code?

Comment: yes i have created and installed it in my mobile. But i have deleted my apk file after installing it in mobile.

Comment: I have opened a ticket in ionic.io webpage